# Executar HTML do servidor interno PHP 7.1.11

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber se é possível (e se sim, como) executar arquivos HTML a partir do servidor embutido do PHP (versão 7.1.11).

Estou seguindo a apostila da Caelum HTML, CSS e PHP. No curso, após construir as páginas em HTML, chega a hora de instalar o PHP. Instalei, iniciei e deu tudo certo. Navego até o diretório que contém os arquivos HTML e inicio o servidor com `php -S 0.0.0.0:8080` pra ficar acessível na rede. Porém, ao chamar o `index.html` no navegador eu obtenho um "*The requested resource / was not found on this server.*"; porém, se eu mudo a extensão do `index.html` para `index.php` a página é executada (só não abre as imagens).

Comment: Você sabe iniciar o servidor? Qual é a estrutura da pasta do projeto? O que já tentou fazer?

Comment: Olá Anderson, eu estou seguindo a apostila da Caelum html, css e php. No curso após construir as páginas em html chega a hora de instalar o php. Até ai tudo bem instalei e iniciei e deu tudo certo. Navego até o diretório que contém os arquivos html e inicio o servidor com "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080" pra  ficar acessível na rede. Porém ao chamar o index.html no navegador eu  obtenho um "The requested resource / was not found on this server." porém se eu mudo a extensão do index.html para index.php a página é executada (só não abre as imagens).

Comment: Pode detalhar na pergunta todo o processo que executou? Colocando a estrutura de pastas, comandos executados e conteúdos dos arquivos? Eu testei aqui e o `index.html` abriu sem problemas.

Comment: Mudei o local do projeto e agora funcionou. Apenas coloquei a pasta do projeto "mirrorfashion" (com o arquivo index.html) um diretório acima em "C:\users\david\documentos". Fiz o mesmo processo para iniciar o servidor: entrei no NOVO diretório do projeto pelo prompt de comando (cd users/david/documents) e iniciei com "php -S 0.0.0.0:8080" e agora funciona. Se eu mudo para o local anterior (C:\users\david\documentos\computação) e inicio o servidor a partir de lá não funciona. O php tá descompactado em C:\. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela atenção, seu comentário foi bastante útil.

Comment: Talvez a aplicação não respondeu bem aos acentos em `computação`. Teste sem os acentos e veja se funciona.

Comment: Na mosca cara !! Tirei o acento e o cedilha de computação e rodou legal. Valeu brother.